# Fody PropertyChanged does not trigger another property

Tags: c#, fody-propertychanged

I'm working on a WPF project. To prevent a lot of boiler code I'm using Fody PropertyChanged. This is a snippet of my problem:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class MyViewModel : MyViewModelBase
{
    public bool HasCardSet
    {
        get
        {
            return Person != null && Person.Card != null;
        }
    }

    public void SavePerson()
    {
        Person.Card = new Card();
    }
}

[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class MyViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Card Card { get; set; }
}

[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Card : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SomeOtherClass> Items { get; set; }
}
```

When I call `SavePerson()` (in `MyViewModel`), It won't trigger the `HasCardSet` property. 
I've added the `PropertyChangedNotificationInterceptor` and see that property "Card" changes on target "People". But my breakpoint in `HasCardSet` does not trigger.

Comment: how would binding now, that HasCardSet has changed, if it's not a part of a Person?

Comment: Well, my Person has another property Info (class), and that has a string property Name. (Person.Info.Name) If I change it in code, my binding in XAML gets updated. So why does that work, and this doesn't?

Comment: @OP: It depends a lot on the way you update the property (do you set the Person's Info property or just the Name of this property ?) and the binding itself. More of your code may help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `HasCardSet` property has to be declared in the `Person` class.

Then, as suggested in the [documentation](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/On_PropertyName_Changed), add this method :

```
public void OnCardChanged()
{
    HasCardSet = Card != null;
}
```

This will trigger the expected `PropertyChanged` event.

Note that your `Binding` should have your `Person` object as `DataContext`, not directly your View Model.

Comment: Moved HasCardSet to Person, and updated XAML to listen to Person.HasCardSet. This worked! Didn't use the OnCardChanged.